# Mac OS Big Sur R compilation error: ld: framework not found CoreFoundation

Tags: r, rcpp, xcode12

After my Xcode automatically updated itself to 12.4, my Rstudio package compilation breaks and throws the following error:

```
    ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried reinstalling Xcode command-line tool; disabling csrutil and then manually creating links, but these attempts were to no avail. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: See the discussion here: https://github.com/rmacoslib/r-macos-rtools/issues/42

Answer (score 4):

add `-F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/` into LDFLAGS

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error by:

1. Installing XCode CLI (you can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=for%20Xcode)
2. Removing ~/.R/Makevars and ~/.Renviron (you can just rename them if you don't want to delete them)
3. Installing `gfortran` from here: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases

Comment: Removing the Makevars and .Renviron files did work for me, seems blunt though. I ended up deleting everything in Makevars but replacing it with everything suggested here: https://pat-s.me/transitioning-from-x86-to-arm64-on-macos-experiences-of-an-r-user/